# Problem in writing code in Ms-Access

Tags: ms-access

I am using a Master Form under which another subform is attached so that all the records of child table is displayed based on the parent table's primary key. All the child records are displayed but the whole records of parent table is not shown, only the default value is displayed again & again.Please help.

Comment: You're going to have to explain the problem in more detail.  What do you mean by "The default value is displayed again & again"

Answer (score 0):

Is seems that the controls may not be bound to fields (columns) in the master table. Check the Control Source of your fields in design view and ensure that they show the names of  fields.

Alternatively, the master form could be in a new record, but it does not seem likely that the child records would be displaying properly, if this were the case.